Examples of non-maximal orders in non-Archmidean fields that are not monogenic
Suppose I have a number field $K$ and a non-Archimedean place $v$.
I know that the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_{K_v}$ is monogenic.
That means $\mathcal{O}_{K_v}=\mathbb{Z}_p[\alpha]$
for some $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_{v}$ where $p$ is the prime below $v$.
But now suppose I have a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-order $\mathcal{O} \subseteq \mathcal{O}_{K_v}$, then I don't think one should have that the order is monogenic. But I cannot find an easy counterexample.

Ah! Nice use of ramified primes!
